# Laravel - multiple value in where clause

Tags: laravel

I need to do search using laravel 5.4. I have next fields to search

I want to search this 7 fields. I use this query:

```
if ($categoryIn <> ''  AND 
    $brandIn == ' '    AND 
    $model == ' '      AND 
    $fuelIn == ''      AND 
    $priceMinIn == '0' AND 
    $priceMaxIn == '0' AND 
    $kmm == '0') {
    $cars = Cars_models::Where('Categorie', 'LIKE',  $categoryIn )->get ();
}
else if ($categoryIn <> ''     AND 
            $brandIn <> ' '    AND 
            $model == ' '      AND 
            $fuelIn == ''      AND 
            $priceMinIn == '0' AND 
            $priceMaxIn == '0' AND 
            $kmm == '0') {
    $cars = Cars_models::Where('Categorie','LIKE',$categoryIn)
            ->Where('Brand', 'LIKE',  $brandIn)
            ->get ();
} else if...
```

But I have to many combinations. Can anyone help me show me an easier way? Because I can not handle it if I write like this every combination.

Any idea?

Comment: See here this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511015/writing-a-function-in-laravel

Comment: Great you've got solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's many ways to do this. The simplest one is:

```
$q = Cars_models::query();
if ($categoryIn) { $q->where("categorie","LIKE",$categoryIn); }
if ($brandIn) { $q->where("Brand","LIKE", $brandIn); }   
if ($model) { $q->where("model","LIKE",$model); } 
... 
$cars = $q->get();
```

Alternatevely you can do:

```
$conditions = collect([ 
          [ "categorie", "LIKE", $categoryIN ], 
          [ "Brand", "LIKE" , $brandIn ],
          ...
          ])->filter(function ($value) { return !empty($value[2]); }); //Remove all conditions with an empty second part

$cars = Cars_models::where($conditions->all())->get();
```